# What is nvidia gpu performance scale in BIOS?

Tags: bios, lenovo-laptop, nvidia-graphics-card

I recently updated my BIOS from 1.14 to 2.01 on my lenovo Y50. A new setting was added in my bios called nvidia gps(gpu performance scale), there was no description i can only enable or disable. i couldn't find anything about it on Google. Any body have any idea to what this is. I didn't find a difference when i disabled it and there is nothing in the BIOS update log about any change.

http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-y-series-laptops/y50-70-notebook-lenovo/downloads/DS100998

Answer (score 2, accepted):

turn it ON! Nvidia Card does scaling if this option is on, less latency then onbaord intel gpu. Use it if you play games. TUrn off if you want that intel does scaling, this involves scaling problems but better performance if use your gpu for rendering where latency doesn´t matter.

And of course turn it on if you have the UHD Version of Y50 - less laggy feeling, less errors from games when they want to scale.

Comment: hey thanks ! but can i get more details like when you mean by scaling it means about the resolution or something? and how do you about the latency decrease , can i know your source ? Im a power user so id like to know. i have the FHD version.

Comment: since you have mentioned it i have started to notice the random latency issues while playing games. but when i turn it on i notice the fps drops slightly or maybe its the placebo effect.

Comment: My FPS was cut in HALF all of a sudden lately. However, when I disabled nvidia gps everything went back to normal fps again! So at least for me, it's hugely problematic.

Answer (score 0):

turn it OFF! I have a Lenovo laptop with an 860M that started having terrible FPS. Over much research with little result, I finally decided to disable "nvidia gps" in the BIOS. Immediately my FPS went back to full as my gpu frequency was no longer throttled. I'm hoping this info will help someone else.